Multiple regression or mixed-model to account for altitude in model
Let's say I'd like to test the concentration of a particular mineral (conc) in different parts (part) of two different mountains (A and B). Here's an example dataset:
df <- data.frame(conc=c(0.10,0.11,0.15,0.16,0.22,0.24,0.25,0.34,0.34,0.36, 0.35,0.36,0.36,0.36,0.37,0.33,0.34,0.29,0.22,0.20,0.17,0.11,0.03,0.03,0.02,0.02,0.01,0,0,0.01), mountain=rep(c('A','B'),each=15), part=rep(c("foot","hillside","top"), each=5, times=2), altitude1=rep(seq(1,5), times=6), altitude2=rep(seq(1,15), times=2))

My initial idea was to simply run a linear regression
mod <- lm(conc ~ part*mountain, data=df)

However, I'm not sure this is correct because the different observations for each mountain are not independent (they correspond to different altitudes for each mountain), right?
I thought maybe a mixed-model would be appropriate in this case but I'm not sure whether I should include a random effect of different altitude levels for each part of a mountain (altitude1) or overall altitude for the whole mountain (altitude2).

If the observations are at different altitudes this would not constitute non-independence - it might be a confound though. If observations were from the same mountain or mountain range, that would constitute non-independence.

@DavidB, thank you for your comment! A and B are indeed two particular mountains, so there is non-independence. Sorry for being unclear (I edited the question)

@DavidB so I need to add a random effect of altitude to the model right? Would it be lmer(conc ~ part*mountain + (1|altitude1) or lmer(conc ~ part*mountain + (1|altitude2)?

Alright. So with only two mountains the statistical mechanics of a mixed effect model with random intercepts won't work. Mountain has to be a fixed effect. However, you mention altitude as a potential random intercept. To me, this suggests that the spatial proximity of samples within a mountain is important - is that correct? Adjusting for spatial proximity is not simple. Some methods that might be applicable have been developed in Ecology (see for example https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12390).

"this suggests that the spatial proximity of samples within a mountain is important - is that correct?" Yes, that's correct.
But why can't a standard lme model be fit on these data? Something like lmer(conc ~ part*mountain + (1|altitude1) for example. Would it be wrong to run a model like that?

In that model, altitude is the random intercept. Random intercepts are always categorical variables. That means both that all observations from the same altitude are equally similar (fine), and that all altitudes are equally dissimilar - probably not true.

thanks, that's helpful! "all observations from the same altitude are equally similar", by similar you mean that they are measuring the same effect for each level of altitude, right?
"all altitudes are equally dissimilar", if a unit increase of the level of altitude corresponds to an increase of 200 meters, isn't this assumption also satisfied? For example, a value of 1 for altitude corresponds to the first 200 meters, a value of 2 to the next 200 meters, and a value of 15 to the last 200 meters.

altitude in my example is supposed to be categorical and each unit increase in value corresponds to an increase in 200 meters.

What I mean by "all observations from the same altitude are equally similar" is that, for example, the similarity between altitude = 1 and altitude = 2 is the same as the similarity between  altitude = 1 and altitude = 3, etc.

Thanks! But then I don't really understand what you mean by "altitudes are equally dissimilar - probably not true". So if altitude=1 corresponds to 0-200 meters, and altitude=2 to 201-400 meters, will that satisfy this requirement?

Random intercepts are non-ordered factors. It'll only work if that's an appropriate way to model your data

You would need a mixed model if you have multiple measures on particular mountains, because then there might be something about a mountain (other than the part or type) that is affecting the concentration (e.g. its location, the climate there, etc).
You would then want a random effect for mountain.
It's fine to have repeated values of one of the variables in a model -- this happens all the time. E.g. if you look at height as a function of age and sex in human children, you will surely have many girls and boys, but a regular regression is fine. However, if you had boys and girls from the same families, you would need to account for that.

thanks for your answer. I actually want to compare mountains A and B (they are two particular mountains), so that would be a fixed effect (I edited my question, because it wasn't clear).

The question is then, if I have different observations for the same mountains (A and B), then which variable should I select for my random effect? Should it be lmer(conc ~ part*mountain + (1|altitude1) or lmer(conc ~ part*mountain + (1|altitude2) or something else?

The random effect should be mountain because that's what is causing the dependency in the errors.

thanks! But the idea is to compare concentrations between the two mountains A and B (actually test for the interaction part*mountain), so mountain needs to be a fixed effect, doesn't it?

Maybe it's still not clear in my question that I only have data for two specific mountains and I would like to compare concentration levels between these two mountains. That's why I'm slightly confused what my random effect should be here. I believe it has to be either altitude1 (altitude for each part of the mountain) or altitude2 (altitude for the entire mountain), because that is the repeated measure for each mountain. Is that not right?
